# How to change the format of addresses on a substrate local blockchain?

Tags: substrate-node-template, address

I have run a local node on my local host using the substrate documentation at:

https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/build-local-blockchain/

Also I git cloned the UI Frontend for displaying the details.

As you know on a Polkadot blockchain, or a local node created using the substrates, addresses are in 3 different formats as below:

Chain address type  Address:

```
Polkadot (SS58):
    15oF4uVJwmo4TdGW7VfQxNLavjCXviqxT9S1MgbjMNHr6Sp5

Kusama (SS58):
    HNZata7iMYWmk5RvZRTiAsSDhV8366zq2YGb3tLH5Upf74F

Generic Substrate chain (SS58):
    5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY
```

I want to know if and how we can change the format of these addresses on a `Generic Substrate` chain.

for example we want the addresses to begin with these three letters: "aml".

Is there any way to make that happen on a local blockchain and how?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Change it here.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/f0c14f387baba0688afa9422a9bc24068d431716/bin/node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs#L200

---

And the letters depend on the ss58 hash algorithm.

The prefix range is `0 ~ 65535(u16::MAX)`. Maybe some of these numbers will derive the `aml` starting.

It's impossible to specify the letters manually.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried this and changed the number from 42 to 100. and even tried other numbers. Still getting the same type of addresses.